# MSAL library sign in without response

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, outlook, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying an application that is able to display all and create new events for the Outlook calendar. I am using the MSAL library to get the authentication code. The problem is that although the login screen appears when I touch the buttons enter or cancel I do not notice any reaction. This is my code:

```
class OutlookManagerController: BaseViewController {
    let oClientKey = "a07745a5-3b90-4385-a2b2-8223dbf68688"
    let authScopes = ["openid+https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read+offline_access"]

    func getAcessToken(){
        if let application = try? MSALPublicClientApplication.init(clientId: oClientKey) {
            application.acquireToken(forScopes: authScopes) { (result, error) in
                if result != nil {
                    let userToken = result!.accessToken!
                    print(userToken)

                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Unable to create application.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MSAL automatically passes `openid` and `offline_access` so you do not need to pass those.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that you are not listening for the return of the auth code from the `SFSafariViewController` which MSAL launches when you call `AcquireToken()`. MSAL uses the `SFSafariViewController`for login in order to enable better security and provide Single Sign-On across applications. You just need to set up a redirect URI that has the ability to call back your application and use the correct Issuer for your tenant.

*That is the problem you are running in to. Sign in is successful, but Azure can't find it's way back to your app!*

First, some groundwork.

## **System Webviews**

Most modern OAuth2 libraries now use the System Webview for signing a user in. A System Webview is a browser component that an application can launch that appears to be part of the application but is actually an isolated process which runs the operating system's web browser. For iOS this is the [`SFSafariViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) and on Android it is [`Chrome Custom Tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs).

The benefit of the System Webview for singing a user in are numerous, including:

- ***Better security***. An application can not access the credentials typed in to a System Webview as it's an isolated browser process.

  *Today many applications use a username and password form or an embedded webview to get credentials. This allows an application to listen in and grab these credentials. Many companies have begun disallowing applications that have this kind of sign in. System Webviews ensures your app doesn't have this problem.*
- ***Single Sign-On***. Once a user has signed in with the System Webview, a cookie is placed in the browser and that account is available to any application, preventing the need for a user to sign in to every app separately.

  *As more consumers and businesses leverage phone SMS and other factors as additional steps, having to redo this step as well as use your password is getting very annoying for customers. System Webviews remove this problem.*
- ***Better control.*** A user can choose which account to provide the application, or add a brand new account in the System Webview if supported.

You've seen Google and Microsoft make the transition to this System Webview with our latest SDKs as well as update our identity services, and it's to give the customer these protections and features. App Auth from the OpenID project, which has code contributed by both Google and Microsoft engineers among others, also provides this support.

## **System Webview Needs To Return Back To Your App**

One of the things that might have occurred to you reading the above is this:

***If an application now calls a System Webview for sign-in, and has no control over it, how do I get the tokens I need back from the System Webview?***

The answer is that you must leverage the mechanisms each operating system has to call back the application, and then use the `redirectURI` from the OAuth2 protocol to return the response back to that application using that mechanism. It's almost exactly like how this works in a web browser. You get redirected away from the website to an identity provider for sign in, and then the identity provider uses the `redirectURI` to return the user back to the website with tokens in the response somewhere.

For iOS this done through Custom URL Schemes. A URL scheme is in the format of `CFBundleURLScheme:\\CFBundleURLSchemes` and is defined as:

- ***CFBundleURLName***
  A string containing the abstract name of the URL scheme. To ensure uniqueness, it is recommended that you specify a reverse-DNS style of identifier, for example, com.acme.myscheme.
  The string you specify is also used as a key in your app’s InfoPlist.strings file. The value of the key is the human-readable scheme name.
- ***CFBundleURLSchemes***
  An array of strings containing the URL scheme names—for example, http, mailto, tel, and sms.

To register a URL type for your app, include the `CFBundleURLTypes` key in your app’s `Info.plist` file. The `CFBundleURLTypes` key contains an array of dictionaries, each of which defines a URL scheme the app supports.

## **How To Get A System Webview To Return To Your App**

So, combining these two things, it's fairly simple what you need to do:

1. Figure out what your URL scheme will be for your app (e.g. `appauth://abc123`.
2. Tell Azure AD what your new URL scheme is, adding it as another  `redirectURI` for your application.
3. Configure your application to listen for this URL scheme and launch the app
4. Configure the application itself to grab the token once this URL scheme launches your app (App Auth, as well our own MSAL libraries, do this for you!)

### 1. Figure out what your URL scheme will be for your app

You can read up on how to make URL schemes from Apple's Inter-App Communication documentation, but we recommend you use the scheme of `appauth://<client id>` (e.g. `appauth://ab032846-efee-481f-b6bc-493aae92c432`)

### 2. Tell Azure AD what your new URL scheme is

You need to add this URL scheme as a RedirectURI to your app. This is easy to do. Just visit https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and select your application. Scroll down to Custom App URIs under `Native Applications` and add your new redirectURI!

[image: A snapshot of the place in the developer portal where you need to enter in this information]

### 3. Configure your application to listen for this URL scheme

Add the following to your `info.plist` file as per Apple's instructions in Inter-App Communication. It should look something like this, although different apps will have different and additional URL schemes registered:

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>ab032846-efee-481f-b6bc-493aae92c432</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>app-auth</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

### 4. Configure the application itself to grab the token

Although listening for a response back from a web browser to an application is a well known pattern for all iOS apps, ***the actual implementation varies by the identity SDK you use***. For MSAL put the following code in your `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    print("Received callback!")

    MSALPublicClientApplication.handleMSALResponse(url)


    return true
}
```

The code is rather easy to understand once you know the background above. This is all about receiving a response from the identity service by grabbing the URL that is returned and then giving everything in that URL back to the app so it can grab the tokens it needs to continue it's work.

## That's it!

Your app should now work with Azure Active Directory. This pattern of the System Webview is common both across many Identity Providers (Microsoft, Google, Facebook) and mobile platforms.

This is documented in our [sample application here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2/blob/dev/MSALiOS/AppDelegate.swift#L93).

Answer (score -1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    MSALPublicClientApplication.handleMSALResponse(url)
    return true
}
```